# NodeJS command line does not recognise 'install'

Tags: node.js, command-line, updatecommand

[screenshot of nodeJs command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsCL.png)

My node.js command line says 'install' is not recognised as an internal/external command when I try to update it, according to the installation instructions from a third party website.

Do I need to worry about updating node.js? I am about to embark on an exercise and want to ensure the programme is running correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `npm` should have been installed globally when you installed node. Try `npm -v`.

Comment: Node.js is not a package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install a package from npm then you need to use

```
npm install <package> [options] .
```

and not node install.